# How to use Resources.resx dynamically i,e add new items dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Can anyone please tell me how to Add resources (image, string etc) in 'Resources.resx' dynamically.
I need to add a new bitmap to the Resources.resx from the program at runtime.
The code i used is
     `  **ResourceWriter rw;
      rw = new ResourceWriter("myResources.resources")**;

```
  rw.AddResource("anImage", new Bitmap("winter.jpg"));

  rw.AddResource("welcomeString", "www.java2s.com");
  rw.Generate();`
```

But i found nothing in Resources.resx. Kindly tell me how to use ResourceWriter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ResourceWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcewriter.aspx) to do just that, but I wouldn't recommend writing dynamic resources to resx files. Instead I would use some kind of database (i.e. embedded one).

**EDIT on invalid answer**

I am sorry, I wasn't precise. My suggestion tells you how to create compiled resource file (the one with .resources extension), not original .resx file. The code below works in terms, that it is able to write image (as System.Drawing) to a file named my.resources. You could surely read one out with ResourceReader:

```
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            IResourceWriter writer = new ResourceWriter("my.resources");
            writer.AddResource("myImage", bitmap);
            writer.Close();
        }
```

It seems that you need to do `Close()` instead of `Generate()`. I think that by closing resource stream you force it to be written to disk.
You can make sure that it is there by previewing the file (my.resources, that is) with some hex editor.

Comment: Yes, i know about it but i am not able to use it.The code i used have been added to the question.But i found no image in Resources.resx.

Comment: @Nitinzz: The code I am attaching surely works. Of course it was tested on Winforms and not WPF but I really don't think it should matter.

Comment: @Powel:Yes, it works but before using it I created a mess. I used writer.close() but nothing was happening. So, i changed "my.resources" i,e the file name to Resources.resx. The change was made in Resources.resx and it got corrupted. Now it shows it as illegal Resources.resx. ANY HELP FOR THAT??? How to recover Resources.resx back to original?

Comment: I am afraid that unless you are working under some sort of version/source control system it really can't be done :/ You might try renaming current file and create blank one instead, but I don't think Visual Studio will populate it with missing resources.