# dynamically add values to resources (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, azure, resx

I want to add values to the resources dynamically through codings(C#). My below coding runs without any error but the values are not getting added to the resource file.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (ResXResourceWriter resx = new ResXResourceWriter("Resources.resx"))
    {
        resx.AddResource( "joth", "joth");
        resx.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I think this might be what you are seeking.
I hope it helps you !

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686370/how-to-use-resources-resx-dynamically-i-e-add-new-items-dynamically

Comment: tried everythng but din get anything. what value should be provided within braces  ("Resources.resx")  
is what i used is rite?

Comment: add save changes because you are added successfully but not saved ,so before close save the changes.

Comment: how can i code for saving the changes made?

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (ResXResourceWriter resx = new ResXResourceWriter("Resources.resx"))
    {   resx.AddResource( "joth", "joth");
        resx.Save();
        resx.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I got the following error if i use resx.save(); 
  
(Error 1 'System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter' does not contain a definition for 'Save' and no extension method 'Save' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Jothieshwar\Desktop\jothieshwar\Backup\Project\begin\CS\RDImageGallery_WebRole\login.aspx.cs 113 22 RDImageGallery_WebRole)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above it doesn't seem to work, I looked around and try editing the resx file like a xml file and it worked for me.

```
<data name="v13" xml:space="preserve">
   <value>Test TEst</value>
</data>
```

Above is the structure of a single key/value pair in the resx file opened in nodepadd ++

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath(@"~\App_GlobalResources\myResource2.resx"));

XElement data = new XElement("data");

XNamespace ns = "xml";
data.Add(new XAttribute("name", "v13"));
data.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xml + "space", "preserve"));

data.Add(new XElement("value", "Test TEst"));

doc.Element("root").Add(data);
doc.Save(Server.MapPath(@"~\App_GlobalResources\myResource2.resx"));
```