# Adding a new Key/Value pair to a Resx file in c# MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, resx

Been researching for a bit on how to add a new name and value to a Resx file, i keep coming across the ResXResourceReader but doesn't show up for me after adding the Using System.Resources.

In retrospect I would've just moved this to the DB as I only have a couple resx files so I wasn't too concerned until they demanded an admin that needs the ability to edit and add to these files, but it's too late at this point.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Changing Resx file requires re-compilation... Are you sure it is what you are looking for?

Comment: As Alexei suggest there is a way to update resx files but whenever they changed resx file whole application will restart and your application will loose all the current sessions. As it's just like application pool in recycle.

Comment: Ugh Thanks for the info guys,  I'll look into another solution for the admin instead of them adding translations directly to the resx files

Comment: try this should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003365/dynamically-add-values-to-resources-c/46818210#46818210

Answer (score 0):

To reply to the question asked, resx files are xml-formatted and you can add your own Key-Value pairs under the root node:

```
<root>

  ...

  <data name="This is a Name" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>This Is a Value</value>
  </data>
</root>
```

And this can for instance be done by:

```
        var doc = XDocument.Load(@"filename.resx");
        var element = 
            new XElement("data", 
                new XAttribute("name", "This is a Name"), 
                new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xml + "space", "preserve"), 
                new XElement("value", "This Is a Value"));

        doc.Element("root").Add(element);
        doc.Save(@"output.resx");
```

To get the new resources added to your application however, you need to recompile the project since the resx file is used by VS to generate code which in turn is compiled (usually called Filename.Designer.cs for Filename.resx).