# is it possible to open image and then add it in the resources?

Tags: vb.net

this is my code

```
Private Sub open_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles open_btn.Click

    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        PictureBox1.Load(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    End If
```

if the image is opened, is it possible to add that image in the resources at the same time?
please help me.

Comment: To clarify, you want to add the image to the resources of your program, like embedding it at compile time?

Comment: exactly sir! please help me.

Comment: You're possibly heading off down the wrong route here.  For one, you'll have a hard time getting a process to make any modifications to the file it's running from while it's running.  Perhaps you should be looking instead to create some sort of data file for your application to use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do so, but they will not be a part of your application afterward, if that is the expectation.  Instead, your application will be dependent on an external resources file.

```
Dim result As DialogResult = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
If result = DialogResult.OK Then
    Dim bitmap As New Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName)
    Dim writer = New ResourceWriter("my.resources")
    writer.AddResource("myImage", bitmap)
    writer.Close()
End If
```

Some reference:
[How to use Resources.resx dynamically i,e add new items dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686370/how-to-use-resources-resx-dynamically-i-e-add-new-items-dynamically)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf461k5(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Wow, i didnt know you could do that! Couldnt you just savs the bitmap to a setting? And then write it to an image box when needed?